Python `multiprocessing.Queue` hanging process
For whatever reason, when using Process with Queue from multiprocessing the process hangs when the queue is too big. I haven't investigated yet how big the queue needs to be in order to cause this.
My initial assumption is that the reason for the process to be hanging was that it used a queue, and at the end, the queue was not empty and closed. Having the queue emptied and closed does prevent the problem (demo 3 below), but it also does not happen when the queue has a few items and is left not empty and not closed (demo 1 below). So, I am a bit clueless on it.
Could someone clarify the reason for the process to be hanging?

DEMO

When using p = Process(target=some_function_that_does_not_break), the console output is:

Function started
Function ended
queue size is=100
J1
J2
main ended


When using p = Process(target=some_function_that_also_does_not_break), the console output is

Function started
Function ended. Time filling queue: 1.999461717 seconds
Emptying queue
queue size is=3005706
J1
Queue empty! Time emptying queue: 26.81551289 seconds
Queue closed
J2
main ended

(I have no idea why emptying queue takes way way more time than filling it)

When using p = Process(target=some_function_that_breaks), the console output is

Function started
Function ended
queue size is=3152815
J1
(execution hanging here)


CODE
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Value

q = Queue()
stop = Value("b", False)

# [EDIT]: I added the try...except... to prevent unnecessary comments 
# about the queue being full, which should not happen since 
# it does not have a max size.
def some_function_that_breaks():
    print("Function started")
    try:
        while not stop.value:
            q.put("Item")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Some exception happened: {e}")

    print("Function ended")


def some_function_that_does_not_break(queue_size=100):
    print("Function started")
    for _ in range(queue_size):
        q.put("Item")
    print("Function ended")

def some_function_that_also_does_not_break():
    print("Function started")
    time_start = time.perf_counter_ns()
    while not stop.value:
        q.put("Item")

    time_filling_s = (time.perf_counter_ns() - time_start) / 1e9
    print(f"Function ended. Time filling queue: {time_filling_s} seconds")

    print("Emptying queue")
    time_start = time.perf_counter_ns()
    while not q.empty():
        q.get()

    time_emptying_s = (time.perf_counter_ns() - time_start) / 1e9

    print(f"Queue empty! Time emptying queue: {time_emptying_s} seconds")
    q.close()
    print("Queue closed")


p = Process(target=some_function_that_does_not_break)

p.start()
time.sleep(2)
stop.value = True
time.sleep(1)

print(f"queue size is={q.qsize()}")

print("J1")
p.join()
print("J2")
p.join()

print("main ended")


I believe the reason why emptying takes longer than filling is due to the nature of queue operations in multiprocessing. Putting items into a queue is generally faster than getting items out, especially for large queues, due to how the underlying implementation works. And for the long I understand the reason for the hang is that when a process exits, it needs to clean up all its resources, including the shared queue. For very large queues, this cleanup process can take an extremely long time or even appear to hang indefinitely.

Using a bounded queue can help you avoid the hanging issue by limiting the number of items that can be placed in the queue. In multiprocessing, this can be done by specifying the maxsize argument when creating the Queue. Tip: If you ever to use a third party package you can use Redis (with redis-py library) or ZeroMQ (with pyzmq)

I can answer why emptying a queue takes much longer than filling it and this may help explain why you might hang on termination:
A multiprocessing.Queue instance is built on top of a multiprocessing.Pipe, which has a very limited capacity in the sense that you cannot send a lot of data to a pipe without ultimatekt blocking unless there is another thread/process concurrently receiving the data from the pipe. So how is that I can create a queue instance and constantly put data to the queue without blocking even if no thread/process is getting the data?
When a queue is created and data is put to it, the data is actually placed on a local deque instance and a "hidden" thread is created that takes data from this deque and sends it through the pipe. This thread will ultimately block after some number of bytes have been sent if no thread/process is getting the data. But the thread/process that is doing the put requests to the queue will not block since all that is doing is taking the data and appending it to a deque.
So when you put for example 1,000,000 objects to a queue this happens relatively quickly since the process involved is just appending these objects to a deque. The queue's hidden thread is able to send some of these objects through the pipe but then blocks. Now when we start a process to get this data, the objects sitting on the sending process's deque, which is the 1,000,000 objects that were put less some number that have already been transmitted through the pipe, have to first be sent through the pipe before it can be retrieved and this is a slower operation than the original appending of these objects to a deque.
But why are you hanging when your worker function is some_function_that_breaks?
This is related to the amount of data being put to the queue and can be demonstrated by modifying def some_function_that_does_not_break(queue_size=100) by specifying queue_size=1_000. On my desktop running Python 3.12.2 on either Windows or Debian Linux (using WSL), this too will now result in a hang.
As I have already described, doing a put simply appends the item to a deque and notifies the hidden queue thread that there is data available on the deque. Because of the amount of data written to the queue, this thread is currently blocked waiting for a "getter". There appears to be some process finalization code that attempts to first ensure that all the data that has been put to the queue (still sitting in a deque instance) is transmitted to a "getter" process, of which there is none. This is the cause of the hang. If you only write a small amount of data to the queue that can go though the pipe without the hidden thread blocking, then the process terminates as expected because all of the enqueued data has already been sent.
This is the same reason why a process should never attempt to join another process that has put items on a multiprocessing queue before first emptying the queue by getting all the items that were put on the queue (unless, of course, there is another thread or process doing the getting).
